# Javascript obtener la variable con el valor más alto

Tags: javascript

tengo un codigo que me muestra el valor más alto entre ciertas variables, pero em retorna el valor, hay alguna manera de que retorne el nombre de la variable?

```
perfil = Math.max(puntajeX1, casos, prestaciones , educacion, impuestos);
```

si me da el valor más alto , pero quisiera es el nombre de la variable porque con solo saber el valor no puedo ejecutar x o y función ifs o FOR se que puedo hacerlo pero, quisiera disminuir un poco la cantidad de codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Math.max()` sólo te va a devolver el valor más alto, y no el nombre de la variable. Ten en cuenta que una vez pasados los valores a la función, ésta no sabe cómo se llamaba la variable que contenía cada valor.

Podrías hacer un método sencillo fuera de `Math.max()` usando el operador ternario para ver cuál de las variables es más grande. Y de ese modo ejecutar una operación u otra usando un `switch..case`, pero no dejaría de ser igualmente sencillo (aunque quizás no tan "ordenado") hacer `if..else if...else`.

El código sería algo como esto:

```js
var puntajeX1 = 12, 
    casos = 6, 
    prestaciones = 1, 
    educacion = 15, 
    impuestos = 9;

perfil = Math.max(puntajeX1, casos, prestaciones , educacion, impuestos);

variableMasAlta = puntajeX1 == perfil ? "puntajeX1" :
                  casos == perfil ? "casos" :
                  prestaciones == perfil ? "prestaciones" :
                  educacion == perfil ? "educacion" :
                  impuestos == perfile ? "impuestos" : null;
                  
                  
console.log(variableMasAlta);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias , justo acababa de llegar a la misma conclusion gracias

Answer (score 0):

He intentado interpretar tu consulta de la mejor manera y he armado lo siguiente:

En mi ejemplo obtengo los valores númericos desde un diccionario y luego lo `itero` obteniendo el `key` para posteriormente descubrir cual es la variable.

Podrás examinar la `lógica` en la función `cualEsLaVariableMasAlta`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script>

      var valoresNumericos = {
        variable1: 200,
        variable2: 100,
        variable3: -50
      };

  function cualEsLaVariableMasAlta(valoresNumericos) {

      var max = -Infinity; 
      var maxVar = null;
      for (var key in valoresNumericos) {
         var num = valoresNumericos[key];

         if (num > max) {
             max = num;
             maxVar = key;
         }

         max = (num > max && num) || max;
      }

        return maxVar;
      }

      console.log(cualEsLaVariableMasAlta(valoresNumericos));

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Observando en la consola de tu browser se puede ver el valor Variable1 como el mayor y en base al diccionario realizado, es correcto.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @AndresDevelop Por nada! Me alegra que ya este resuelto!

Answer (score 0):

Como te comentan esa funcion te va a devolver solo el valor y no el nombre de la variable. Con el fin de evitar muchos if o mas lineas de codigo para validar, te recomiendo crear un objeto :

```
var obj = {
   puntajeX1 : puntajeX1,
   casos : casos,
   prestaciones : prestaciones,
   educacion : educacion,
   impuestos : impuestos
}
```

Con sus nombres y sus valores y aplicar el siguiente codigo:

```js
var puntajeX1 = 1022, casos = 5, prestaciones = 20 , educacion = 1, impuestos = 100;
var obj = {
  puntajeX1 : puntajeX1,
  casos : casos,
  prestaciones : prestaciones,
  educacion : educacion,
  impuestos : impuestos
}
var maxKey = Object.keys(obj).sort(function (a, b) {
  return obj[a] < obj[b];
})[0];

var result = {};
result[maxKey] = obj[maxKey];
console.log(result);
```

Lo que haces es ordenar el objeto con el mayor valor hasta el menor, luego obtienes de ese objeto el valor dependiendo de la `key`

Comment: wow es una respuesta muy compleja pero bien eficaz, muchisimas gracias.

Comment: si te queda cualquier duda, preguntame :D no es tan compleja